# SimpleInjector: Registration of class that has data parameters, and a dependency

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

Registration of a service that has only data parameters in it's ctor is easy enough.

```
string emailHost = "emailHost";
int emailPort = 25;
string emailFrom = "fake@fake.cc";

container.Register<IEmailManager>(
    () => new EmailManager(emailHost, emailPort, emailFrom),
    Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

But how do I do it if the class/service has data paramters, *and* an injected service? How can I get that registered `SmsNumberFormatter` into `SmsManager`, which still providing the sms configuration data via ctor?

```
string smsAccountSid = "sid";
string smsAuthToken = "token";
string smsFromNumber = "##########";

container.Register<ISmsNumberFormatter, SmsNumberFormatter>(
    Lifestyle.Singleton);

container.Register<ISmsManager>(
    () => new SmsManager(
        new SmsNumberFormatter(), smsAccountSid, smsAuthToken, smsFromNumber), 
    Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

*SimpleInjector: v 3.3.2.0*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

## 1. Use the container to obtain your dependency

```
container.Register<ISmsManager>(() => 
        new SmsManager(container.GetInstance<ISmsNumberFormatter>(),
        smsAccountSid, 
        smsAuthToken, 
        smsFromNumber), Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

## 2. Turn your basic type parameters into a single injectable class

```
public class SmsManagerOptions
{
    public SmsManagerOptions(string smsAccountSid, string smsAuthToken, string smsFromNumber)
    {
        SmsAccountSid = smsAccountSid ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(smsAccountSid));
        SmsAuthToken = smsAuthToken ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(smsAuthToken));
        SmsFromNumber = smsFromNumber ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(smsFromNumber));
    }

    public string SmsAccountSid { get; }
    public string SmsAuthToken { get; }
    public string SmsFromNumber { get; }
}
```

You than need, of course, to change the `SmsManager` ctor to something like `public SmsManager(ISmsNumberFormatter formatter, SmsManagerOptions options)`.

Then in your DI registration method:

```
var options = new SmsManagerOptions("sid", "token", "######");

container.Register<ISmsNumberFormatter, SmsNumberFormatter>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
container.RegisterSingleton<SmsManagerOptions>(options);
container.Register<ISmsManager, SmsManager>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

**Note**

I believe the second option is cleaner, but you are free to choose the one you like.

Comment: I vote for the second option. Not only cleaner, but allows Simple Injector to keep analyzing your object graphs using its [Diagnostic Services](https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, with the different ways to approach this!

Comment: I would even make `SmsManagerOptions` immutable, with readonly properties and a constructor that accepts the required values. This prevents the `SmsManagerOptions` from being initialized in a faulty state.

Comment: @Steven it totally makes sense. I've updated the answer after your tip.